# Android: Prevent Only Vertical Scrolling in WebView

Tags: java, android, webview, scroll

Here is my code -

```
  // disable scroll on touch
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

But the problem is that it disables all scrolling (horizontal and vertical too). Is there any way to just disable vertical scrolling and keep horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build in method of the `WebView` for disabling the [horizontal scroll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) which is easy than manipulating the `OnTouchListener` of the WebView

**solution:**

```
webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

EDIT:

wrap it in horizontal scrollview

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/mywebview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yes it works fine to allow only horizontal scroll but there becomes a definite delay in loading web view and hangs the app as well.